# Doing Transactions with Hyperledger Composer on daily basis (from logic.js)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

is there a way to do a certain kind of Transaction on a daily basis (at a certain time) using the logic.js file? I know that there are timestamps that you can add to an asset, but I don´t see how that could be used to haven an automatic transaction. Is there some other solution maybe? Or do i need an application wrapped around hyperledger fabric for that?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't do it from the logic.js file, but you could use the Composer Node API to call the transaction every day, achieving what you want to do?

[Example of a Transaction](https://github.com/Chris-McQueen-Development/logistics-chain/blob/master/utility-scripts/manufactureCar.js)

You are right, that is an application wrapped around. But it's pretty lightweight, the only issues I had were getting my head around authentication. [Here is a utility script](https://github.com/Chris-McQueen-Development/logistics-chain/blob/master/utility-scripts/connection-util.js) to help with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It would work too, most likely that is the way I will do it. It just would have been cleaner if I could have done it all with one tool. As i want to make one contract, which will dissolve in many transactions, I will now need an additional database etc. ...

Do you know if there is another tool which is capable to achieve my goal, or can I do it directly on the commandline with fabric?